# How to cast Class<?> to Class<? extends X>?

Tags: java, casting

I have a class `A` saved as `Class<?>` which I know is a subclass of B and have to cast this into a `Class<? extends B>`. But my code does not compile:

```
Class<?> c = ...
if (c.newInstance() instanceof B) { // true
    Class<? extends B> = (B) c; // does not compile
}
```

During my research, I've found out about wildcard captures, but I don't know how to use this method, because B is an `abstract` class.
So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `c.asSubclass(B.class)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.lang.Class` has a method to do exactly that: [`asSubclass(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass(java.lang.Class)).

With that, you can write the above code as:

```
if (c.isAssignableFrom​(B.class)) {
    Class<? extends B> b = c.asSubclass(B.class);
}
```

Comment: I believe that the use of `asSubclass` is correct. However, am I right that it should be `B.class.isAssignableFrom(c)`?

Answer (score 2):

Simply cast to the **right** type:

```
Class<? extends B> b = (Class<? extends B>) c;
```

First of all, the type on the left hand side says `Class<? extends B>`, whereas the type you use in your cast uses `B`. *Some class extending B* isn't the same as *B*. *Class of B* and *B* aren't the same.

Then: there is also a syntax error, as you omitted a variable name, too.